# When audience and issuer in JWT token is enabled, is it supposed to prevent using the token from any other URL? Or is it only part of the token?

Tags: .net, authentication, jwt, token, bearer-token

I defined the issuer and audience to something random but I'm still able to make calls on postman as long as the issuer and audience are same in both definition of token and generating of it.

When authenticating isn't it supposed to check the request url and compare it with audience I have set?

Here is the definition of the token:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x => {

 x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options => {
 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {

  IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
  ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
  ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
  ValidateIssuer = true,
  ValidateAudience = true,
  ValidateLifetime = true,
  ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

 };
 options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents {
  OnAuthenticationFailed = context => {
   if(context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException)) {
    context.Response.Headers.Add("IS-TOKEN-EXPIRED", "true");
   }
   return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
 };
});
```

and here is the part generating token:

```
 public Token? GenerateToken(string email) {
  try {
   var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
   var tokenKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iconfiguration["JWT:Key"]!);
   var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
      {
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
        {
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),



        }),

    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
    Issuer = iconfiguration["JWT:Issuer"],
    Audience = iconfiguration["JWT:Audience"],
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
   };
   var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

   return new Token { Access_Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token) };
  } catch(Exception) {
   return null;
  }
 }
```

I have tried on couple different frameworks, .net and node.

Comment: If it is only in the token that validation is taking place what's the use of audience and issuer? Can't I just add a few more claims instead?